# How can I ask for extra ingredients in a dish?

Tags: mandarin

How can I ask for more of an ingredient in a dish? like add extra cheese, extra meat, etc. Not that it matters but I specifically want to know this for 手抓餅.

Comment: In Taiwan, we usually say something like：「老闆，可不可以多放點蔥？」or「老闆，多加些cheese好不好？」If you will pay for it, you can say 「老闆，多加十塊錢肉。」

Comment: 手抓饼 dish? why not cake? ingredient to be added before baking? Note (iciba):

手抓饼原名葱抓饼，起源于台湾。04年由上海粮全其美食品有限公司从台湾引进大陆，更名为手抓饼。正宗手抓饼，新鲜出炉后千层百叠，层如薄纸，用手抓之，面丝千连，其外层金黄酥脆，内层柔软白嫩，一股葱油与面筋的香味扑鼻而来，让每个人来不及等待，抓起就吃……04年至今，一直风靡全国，可搭配鸡蛋，培根，蔬菜等辅料，老少皆宜。

Comment: Is 手抓餅 really originally from Taiwan?

Answer (score 2):

If the ingredient you asking for more is free, like condiments (salt, sugar, oil) or side greens (onion, pickle) you can say "多 ~ ":

> 多盐，多糖，多油, 多洋葱，多泡菜

If the ingredient you asking for more will be charged money, like main topping (meat, seafood) or staple food (noodle, rice)  Then you can say "加 ~" :

*Some western restaurant offer free bread*.

> 加鱼肉， 加牛肉， 加猪肉， 加面条， 加饭

Some restaurant have set price for extra ingredient and some don't, so you should ask how much it costs to have extra something.

To get a larger size dish, you can say 加大码, again, Some restaurant have set price for extra large size dishes and some don't, you have to ask for the the price.

I  often order 例半 (one and a half order) if there are a lot of people in the party. Since 例半 is one and a half order, I would expect it would be one and a half price.

Here are some examples of how you order extra

- 牛肉炒麵，多洋蔥 (beef stir fry boodle, more onion)
- 牛肉炒麵，加牛肉 (beef stir fry boodle, extra beef) - *ask the price or state how much more money you want to pay for it e.g. "加十元牛肉" (add ten dollar beef)*
- 牛肉炒麵，加大码 (beef stir fry boodle, large size) *ask the price*
- 牛肉炒麵，例半 (beef stir fry boodle, one and a half order) pay 50% more
- 馄饨面，加底 (wonton noodle soup, extra noodle) - *加底 means add only extra staple food when the dish is made up of main toppings on stable food base, For example 馄饨面 (wonton noodle soup)*

Answer (score 1):

For 手抓餅, I would say: 老板，来一个手抓饼。加鸡蛋，加培根，加蔬菜.

The common verbs here are **加(add)** and **放(put)**. E.g. 不要放培根；加火腿肠;